# Creating Program selector

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a C# application and i want to show the default program selector like this picture:

[image]

And i want to get the chosen program.

Actually, i've test with this :

```
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL ");
```

But this allow to open a file with the chosen program and doesn't return it.

Have you an idea of how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't return it?

Comment: I means that it does not return the chosen program, it return a Process object and open the program. I just want the chosen program without open it.

Comment: Google Pinvoke SHOpenWithDialog

Comment: Thanks but i read the msdn docs and i don't see how i can get the chosen program. It seems to not return wanted value (return S_OK or H_RESULT).